# Import Objects and Fields from for custom header

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-object, custom-field, header

I want to call fields ( import field of account ) and make them visible in my custom header , but i have an erreur that is generated when i try to deploy my code .

==> The error message :

```
"message": "No MODULE named markup://c:errorPanel found : [markup://c:account_header]",
```

==> JS

```
import { LightningElement, api , wire } from 'lwc';
import { getSObjectValue } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getSingleAccount from '@salesforce/apex/StationHeaderController.getSingleAccount';

import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.CORE_Account_Type__c';
import STATUT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Statut__c';
import Profit_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.RETAIL_Profit_Center_Formula__c';
import IMAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Image__c';



export default class account_header extends LightningElement {


    @api
    myRecordId;

    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.jpg','.png'];
    }

    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        alert('No. of files uploaded : ' + uploadedFiles.length);
    }

    @wire(getSingleAccount) account;

    get name() {
        return this.account.data ? getSObjectValue(this.account.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
    }
    get CORE_Account_Type__c() {
        return this.account.data ? getSObjectValue(this.account.data, TYPE_FIELD) : '';
    }
    get Statut__c() {
        return this.account.data ? getSObjectValue(this.account.data, STATUT_FIELD) : '';
    }

   

}
```

==>HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="myheader slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-page-header__row">
            <lightning-card >
                <template if:true={account.data}>
                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                     
                        <p>{name}</p>
                        <p>{CORE_Account_Type__c}</p>
                        <p>{Statut__c}</p>
                      
                        
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template if:true={account.error}>
                    <c-error-panel errors={account.error}></c-error-panel>
                </template>
            </lightning-card>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

==>Apex

```
public with sharing class StationHeaderController {
   
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static Account getSingleAccount(){
            return [SELECT Id, Name, CORE_Account_Type__c, Statut__c, RETAIL_Profit_Center_Formula__c, Image__c FROM Account LIMIT 1];
        }
    }
```

==> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
     
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
       
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message I'm seeing that there is no LWC named errorPanel. These things are case sensitive, so maybe your component is called ErrorPanel, or something else